# Link a path to an ImageIcon that works everywhere

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I recently wrote program in a JFrame. I am using `static ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("X:/workspace/eclipse/Timer5/rsc/icon.png");` and `f1.setIconImage(img.getImage());` to display an icon for the JFrame. My problem is that if the program is exported as a runnable jar, the path on other computers does not work anymore and the icon shows the standard Java icon.

Because I can specify a path like this `logo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/logo.png"));` `g.drawImage(logo, 657, 640, 485, 85, null);` in my label class (which extends JLabel) and it works on other computers or moved files, I wanted to ask if this also works for image icons. If I enter the path like I did with `ImageIO.read()` then no icon is been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to ask if this also works for image icons.

Read the `ImageIcon` API.

You will find a constructor that takes an `Image` as a parameter.

So yes you can and should use the `getResource()` method:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(...);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( image );
JLabel label = new JLabel( icon );
```